# Tweepy "page parameter is invalid" error

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I use python tweepy library.
I am trying to search tweets as in that [doc page](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html#API.search)

```
results = twitterApi.search(
            q = request.args.get("q"),
            rpp = 50,
            page = 2
        )
```

It throws that error **"page parameter is invalid"**. If I remove "page" parameter it works.

How can i search by page?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is known - [Issue 604](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/604).

Also see [Tweeter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), there no information about `page` parameter.

I think you should use `since_id` parameter instead of `page`.

Comment: I dont use twitter api directly. I use tweepy in python. In tweepy doc there is **page** parameter. http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/api.html#API.search

Comment: Possibly documentation is lie or outdated. There no support of page parameter look youself: [tweepy/api.py:1176](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/v3.3.0/tweepy/api.py#L1176)

Comment: use count param... see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter gives you only the first 1000 results for a search. 20 results per page * 50 pages = 1000 results. Hence the next hit with the page number 52 onward gives error (not sure why page 51 works, may be to compensate for one or two results filtered in the previous searches).

Refer: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score -1):

Use count param instead.

```
results = twitterApi.search(
            q = request.args.get("q"),
            count=100
        )
```

This call should give you 100 tweets in return.

Comment: I think OP is asking for pagination not the max number to return from a page, which is what rpp does. You probably should use what AndreyT suggested, i.e. the since_id. Or use [cursor](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/cursor_tutorial.html) for pagination.